# How do I simplify Interval[{x,x}] to x?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, intervals

How do I simplify `Interval[{x,x}]` to `x` ?  `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` do not seem to do it.

---

OP comments (inserted by someone else ;)):

> [...] I guess I don't understand why `IntervalUnion[Interval[{x,x}],Interval[{x,y}]]` is not `Interval[{x,y}]` when `x` and `y` are symbolic.

– Paul R. Mar 26 at 6:39

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please provide sample code showing how `Interval` appears.

Comment: Simplify to what? If `x` has a numeric value, `Min` and `Max` of interval are the (same) endpoints.

Comment: Perhaps, you mean a Rule: `Interval[{x,x}]->x`

Comment: @bbgodfrey - a pattern would be better:  `Interval[{y_, y_}] -> y`

Comment: @BobHanlon  Probably so, although it depends on what the OP actually wants.  For instance, he may wish to "simplify" only `Interval[{x,x}]` but not `Interval[{z,z}]`.

Comment: Hmm - I'm just learning to use Interval. I was puzzled that IntervalUnion[Interval[{x,y}],Interval[{y,z}]] did not give Interval[{x,z}]. Is it true that it only deals with numbers, not symbols?

Comment: Anyway, I have expressions like Interval[{x,x}] where x is a number, not a symbol, which I would like to replace with x. Bob Hanlon's pattern suggestion is the one I needed, and it works fine. Many thanks for everyone's answers.

Comment: Scratch that first comment, I can see how that is wrong. I guess I don't understand why IntervalUnion[Interval[{x,x}],Interval[{x,y}]] is not Interval[{x,y}] when x and y are symbolic.

Comment: With your additional comments the problem should be clear after understanding this topic: [98539](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98539/5478)