# Interval calculations in wolfram mathematica

Tags: polynomials, intervals

If `x = Interval[{-100,100}]`, then obviously `x^2 + x = Interval[{-1/4,10100}]`, because as we know, `x^2+x > -1/4`. But *Mathematica* gives me:

```
x^2 + x /. x -> Interval[{-100, 100}]
(* Interval[{-100, 10100}] *)
```

How can I automatically get correct interval `Interval[-1/4,10100]` from *Mathematica*?

Comment: ref / Interval / Possible Issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A different way to go that captures more information than merely the intervals is:

```
result = TransformedDistribution[x^2 + x, Distributed[x, UniformDistribution[{-100, 100}]] ];
Plot[Evaluate[PDF[result, x]], {x, -1, 1}]
(* Discover that the likelihood of various results is not uniform. *)
Interval[{
  Minimize[{x, #}, x, Reals][[1]],
  Maximize[{x, #}, x, Reals][[1]]
} &[Reduce[PDF[result, x] > 0, x]]]
```

We can wrap this in a function (includes streamlining from @ybeltukov ):

```
dependentInterval[func_, marginVar_, varDef___] := Interval[{
  MinValue[{marginVar, #}, marginVar, Reals],
  MaxValue[{marginVar, #}, marginVar, Reals]
} &[Reduce[
  PDF[TransformedDistribution[func, Sequence /@ varDef], 
  marginVar] > 0, marginVar]
]]

dependentInterval[x^2 + x, x, Distributed[x, UniformDistribution[{-100, 100}]] ]
(* Interval[{-(1/4), 10100}] *)
```

Comment: makes sence, thanx!

Comment: @ybeltukov :  You're right.  (Ack.  How did this post make it to the top answer?...)

Answer (score 8):

A possible approach for dependent intervals:

```
Interval@*Through@{MinValue, MaxValue}[u + u^2, {u} ∈ Interval[{-100, 100}]]
(* Interval[{-(1/4), 10100}] *)
```

Comment: That's a new one, what does `@*` mean?

Comment: Is it really impossible to make this searchable in the documentation?  Typing `?@@` works, but `?@@@` or `?@` or `?@*` gives nothing

Comment: I'd be very thankfull if author will explain this strange syntax with @*

Comment: It's `Composition`, as in `Composition[f, g, h][x]` means `f[g[h[x]]]`.  What I don't understand is why it is needed - `f @ g @ h @ x` seems to give the same answer as `f @* g @* h @ x`

Comment: @JasonB [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616) -- There's no need here for `@*`, but `@*` is useful, for example, in `Map`.

Comment: That post is very useful, but I still think Wolfram should do something to make them more searchable in their documentation.

Comment: @JasonB Actually `?` and `@` acts [weird](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkjmm.png) together. Sometimes `@` is any number of lowercase characters and sometimes not.

Comment: @Jason, that shorthand is quite new (haven't gotten used to it myself); I guess they haven't documented it that well just yet.

Answer (score 5):

```
u = Interval[{-100, 100}]
```

According to `ref / Interval / Possible Issues`

> Intervals are always assumed independent

so `u + u^2` is something like `v + u ^ 2` -> `Interval[{-100, 100}] + Interval[{0, 10000}]`.

What can also be surprising, is the fact it is different from  `u + u * u` which we can think of as `v + u * w`.

I the first example `u^2` is at least `0` but in the second `u` can be `-100` while `w` is `100` so the answer is:  `Interval[{-100, 100}] + Interval[{-10000, 10000}]` ->  `Interval[{-10100, 10000}]`

Comment: How can I automatically get correct interval Interval[-0.25,10100] from Mathematica?

Comment: @stiv good point, I should answer the question :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`FunctionRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionRange). For example:

```
IntervalReplace[expr_, x_ -> int_Interval] := Module[{f},
    f = Quiet[
        Check[
            FunctionRange[{expr,{x}\[Element]int},x,y],
            Message[IntervalRange::nmet];
            $Failed,
            FunctionRange::nmet
        ],
        FunctionRange::nmet
    ];
    ToInterval[f, y] /; f =!= $Failed
]

IntervalRange::nmet = FunctionRange::nmet;
```

Then:

```
IntervalReplace[x^2 + x, x -> Interval[{-100, 100}]]
```

> Interval[{-(1/4), 10100}]

More complicated examples:

```
IntervalReplace[1/x + x, x -> Interval[{-100, 100}]]
```

> Interval[{-\[Infinity], -2}, {2, \[Infinity]}]

```
IntervalReplace[x^2+DawsonF[x], x -> Interval[{-11,11}]] //N
```

> Interval[{-0.201125, 121.046}]